# Create multiple tables using single .sql script file in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario where i have to deploy all the tables with a single .sql file. I'm using SQL server management studio by opening the file and clicking execute. I'm getting incorrect syntax with keyword DATABASE and SCHEMA. Would the below .sql script work?

```sql
use database Test_Dev
go
create schema test_schema
go
create table test1(tname1 varchar(50), place1 varchar(100))
go
create table test2(tname2 varchar(50), place2 varchar(100))
go
create table test2(tname2 varchar(50), place2 varchar(100))
go
grant select,insert,delete on schema :: test_schema to "test_user"
```

Comment: Your question is strange as you already claimed that you get incorrect syntax. Therefore the answer to "would this script work" is "no". As a start, you should change `use database Test_Dev` to `use Test_Dev` (see [USE (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16))

Comment: Even with syntax fixes, this script will break on the second `test2` table creation (line 9), as it would already exist

Answer (score 0):

```
USE Test_Dev;
CREATE SCHEMA test_schema;
GO
CREATE TABLE test1(tname1 varchar(50), place1 varchar(100));
CREATE TABLE test2(tname2 varchar(50), place2 varchar(100));
CREATE TABLE test3(tname3 varchar(50), place3 varchar(100));
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON SCHEMA::test_schema TO [test_user];  
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE Test_Dev;
GO

CREATE SCHEMA test_schema;
GO

CREATE TABLE test1 (
tname1 VARCHAR(50),
place1 VARCHAR(100)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE test2 (
tname2 VARCHAR(50),
place2 VARCHAR(100)
);
GO

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON SCHEMA::test_schema TO test_user;
GO
```